# Как вычислить хэш Rfc2898/pbkdf2 на GPU?

Tags: c#, cuda, opencl, криптография

Нужно вычислить хеш pbkdf2 (или Rfc2898) через GPU: желательно использовать OpenCL, но можно и CUDA.

Это вообще как-то можно сделать на C#?
Видел библиотеку на C++:
https://github.com/MichalNawrocik/Rfc2898Gpu

Comment: Если всего один хеш нужно вычислить, то это будет быстрее на CPU. Потому что у GPU задержка большая: пока данные поступят туда, потом, после вычислений, обратно. GPU выгоден, когда нужно сделать миллиарды вычислений.

Comment: Мне нужно вычислять тысячи хешей)

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что видюха будет вычислять этот хеш быстрее? Вы знакомы с алгоритмом? Для CPU реализацию написали? Какие ее части хотите ускорить? Или за вас просто код написать надо? Вы понимаете, что исследование может занять пару дней? Оптимизация - штука не быстрая. Быть может, тогда проще нанять фрилансера за деньги? Вам же крипту считать, верно? Окупится в таком случае. Либо конкретизируйте вопрос, укажите, что именно вызвало трудности при написании кода. И еще: OpenCL использует CUDA, не получится "либо-либо".

Comment: По поводу реализации на C#, не забывайте, что .NET - это проект с открытым исходным кодом. Всё что есть в .NET - имеет исходники на гитхабе https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography/Rfc2898DeriveBytes.cs не ленитесь искать.

Comment: @aepot, нет, мне не крипту считать, а pbkdf2. Реализации для OpenCL уже нашёл, вопрос, как запустить.